# Angular: modifying parent controller from children

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a scenario where two or more Children controllers have to provide additional functionality to their Parent, and this functionality has to be triggered in the Parent context, is good practice to modify Parent `$scope` from Children?

### Example

```
function ParentCtrl(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.customFn = function(){}
  vm.sharedFn = function(name){
    var msg = 'My name is';
    console.log(msg + ' ' + name);
  }
}

function ChildrenCtrl($scope){
  function customFn(){
    $scope.myParent.sharedFn('Batman');
  }
  $scope.myParent.customFn = customFn;
}
```

And call from template:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as myParent">
  <div ng-controller="ChildrenCtrl as myFirstChildCtrl">content</div>
  <div ng-click="myParent.customFn()">click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think so. There will most likely never be a need to do that.. It looks like bad practice to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expanding on @chris's answer, you want a directive.  Directives are designed to be reusable.

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            clickMe: '&'
        },
        template: <div><button ng-click="clickMe({$data:myDirData})>click me</button></div>
})
```

Inside your parent UI's template:

```
 <div>
     <div my-directive click-me="parentControllerFunc($data)"></div>
 </div>
```

Notice that you can pass data back from the directive to the parent controller's callback.

Inside your parent controller's callback you can split the logic up depending on what the arguments are:

```
$scope.parentControllerFunc = function($data){
    //do something specific to the $data
    //do something they ALL will do afterwards
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you trying to do there, but it's probably not a good practise. If what you want is to have a controller reused in the application that inherits properties from some parent scope, or has its own isolated scope, then stick with [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). That's what they are there for.

Comment: What if I have to do this with two or more Children, each Children adding different functionality before calling the Parent? Different directives? or conditionals in the same directive? My goal is to isolate the custom functionality in every Children.

Comment: Sorry, i was away. I suppose you are good now with the answer you got from @jusopi ? you can isolate functionality in each directive and/or inherit functionality from an enclosing controller via bindings (for instance)